# How can one parameter be connected to another parameter in the following code?

Tags: python, parameters

```py
class Node:
  """
  A node class for A* pathfinding.
  :param parent:    parent of the current Node
  :param position:  current position of the Node in the maze
  :param g:         cost from start to current Node
  :param h:         heuristic based estimated cost for current Node to end Node
  :param f:         total cost of present node i.e., : f = g + h

  """

  def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
    self.parent = parent
    self.position = position

    self.g = 0
    self.h = 0
    self.f = 0

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.position == other.position
```

How does `other` parameter connect with the `position` parameter in `other.position`?

Source code: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-star-a-search-algorithm-eb495fb156bb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @cvpp, If I understand, your confusion comes from the fact that in `__init__`, there is a parameter called `position`, in `__eq__`, there is a parameter called `other`, and inside of `__eq__`, there is a reference to `other.position`, which you think looks like two unrelated parameters have been combined? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly that @baileythegreen, can you please explain what it means? And is there a term for it?

Comment: `position` is *not a paramter* in `other.position`. It is an *attribute*.

Comment: @cvpp, I've explained it in an answer so I can be more thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code defines a type of object `Node`; each instance of the `Node` object has four attributes: `position`, `f`, `g`, and `h`.

Instances of the `Node` class of objects also come with the ability to be compared to other `Node`s (we know this because `__eq__()` has been defined for the class).

The `__eq__()` method of the `Node` class takes two instances of the `Node` class as inputs. These are called `self` and `other` in the function definition. Both `self` and `other` have the four attributes belonging to the `Node` object as mentioned above: `position`, `f`, `g`, and `h`.

The values of those attributes are accessed through Python's 'dot notation': e.g., `self.position` gives the position of the object with which the method has been called. `other.position` gives the position of a different `Node` that you're comparing to.

The key here is that `other` refers to an entirely different object, *not another attribute of `self`*. (`other` doesn't have to be a `Node`; the code will work as long as `other` also has an attribute named `position`; otherwise, it will raise an `AttributeError`.)

```py
class Node:
  """
  A node class for A* pathfinding.
  :param parent:    parent of the current Node
  :param position:  current position of the Node in the maze
  :param g:         cost from start to current Node
  :param h:         heuristic based estimated cost for current Node to end Node
  :param f:         total cost of present node i.e., : f = g + h

  """

  def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
    self.parent = parent
    self.position = position
    self.g = 0
    self.h = 0
    self.f = 0

  # Compares the position of itself to a different Node's position
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.position == other.position
```

Comment: One nit: the `other` parameter could be *any* object, not just an instance of `Node`. If that object doesn't have a `position` attribute, an exception will be raised.

Comment: Yes, I debated whether to go into that detail originally. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much @baileythegreen, I didn't know about the `__eq__` function and the `other` parameter before, thank you for the detailed explanation